# Undefined local variable or method `arel_table' after Rails update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I update my app from Rails 5.0.1 to Rails 6.0

Every scope defined with arel stop working.

```
scope :published,      -> { where(state: 'published').where arel_table[:published_at].lteq 'NOW()' }
```

Return me nothing, but the error is

```
Content.where(state: 'published').where arel_table[:published_at].lteq 'NOW()'

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
NameError (undefined local variable or method `arel_table' for main:Object)
```

But

```
Content.arel_table.class
=> Arel::Table
```

**EDIT**

If I use

```
Content.where(state: 'published').where Content.arel_table[:published_at].lteq 'NOW()'
```

The query works but NOW() is NULL

```
 Content Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "contents".* FROM "contents" WHERE "contents"."state" = $1 AND "contents"."published_at" <= NULL ORDER BY "contents"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $2  [["state", "published"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-> { where(state: 'published').where(Content.arel_table[:published_at].lteq(Arel.sql('NOW()'))) }
```

I cannot reach the cause of this change, but I guess it's related to how where clause is evaluated.

I'd suggest not using Arel related method unless you really need it. In this case, you can write simpler code like this:

```
{ where(state: 'published').where("contents.published_at <= ?", Time.current) }
```

Comment: I try, but NOW() is NULL and  so the scope doesn't return any record